# changing default h264 profile

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I need a video stream with main H264 profile. I try to encode it with such command:

```
`ffmpeg -f mjpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i  http://sourse/ -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -vb 64k -preset veryfast -tune film -vsync 1 -f flv rtmp://ip_addres/rtmp/flow`
```

It's ok, but how can I set this profile for default? Because when I don't put put "-profile:v main" option ffprobe show high profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to change the ffmpeg source code and recompile. You can create a preset however.